# Json, webview basic

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

Good day!

I have a WebView, where you get a json and I intend to mount the webview as the received data, this part of the code "html + ="  "+ nmTitle +"  ";"
I put the variable that receives the json content in this part "nmTitle = object.optString (" nmTitle ")", which is above the code within the handler receiving the json.
However, instead of receiving content assigned, my WebView displays the title as "null", it seems, he carries the WebView to later receive json, how to change it for him assign the contents and then send to html ?

```
public class InfoFragment extends Activity {
private AbstractNetworkHandler handler;
String nmTitle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activities_list2);
    final WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    wv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    //this.handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(this, NetworkAction.WEB_VIEW);
    this.handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(super.getBaseContext(), NetworkAction.WEB_VIEW);
    Log.i("webview", "ate aki foi");

    handler.get(23L, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRequestCompleted(final JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
            // final JSONArray array = object.optJSONArray("searchResultsCollection");
            nmTitle = object.optString("nmTitle");

            final JSONArray array = object.optJSONArray("searchResultsCollection");

            String s = String.valueOf(nmTitle);

            // json.setText("My Awesome Text");
            Log.i("webview", s);
            Log.i("webview", "recebendo json");
        }

    }, new HttpFailListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
            Log.i("webview", "falhou ao obter json");
        }
    });
    // (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setSupportZoom(false);

    // wv.loadUrl("http://www.thiengo.com.br/img/system/logo/thiengo-80-80.png");
    String html = "<html>";
    html += "<body>";
    html += "<h1>" + nmTitle + "</h1>";
    html += "<img src=\"http://www.exemplo.com.br/img/system/logo/-80-80.png\" style=\"float: left; display: block; margin-right: 10px;\" />";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        html += "<h3 id=\"h3\" style=\"float: left;\">Texto auxiliar " + (i + 1) + "</h3>";
    }
    html += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    html += "document.getElementById('h3').style.color = '#ff0000';";
    html += "</script></body></html>";

    wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    ll.addView(wv);

}
```

}

Comment: You have to put your html generation and webView loadData code inside `onRequestCompleted`

Comment: I tried it , it returns the following error:11-05 12:06:09.893: W/WebView(1208): java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-39493'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {1c49c489} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {1c49c489})

Comment: i think this tells you that you can load data in WebView in UI thread only, so basically just surround it with `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {public void run() { wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");}});`

Comment: Thanks for the help , but I could just solve by placing the layout of the statements below handler